# Which mathematics are done?

Tags: math-history

I was wondering what fields of mathematics are no longer actively researched. I would imagine algebra (not the abstract kind) and arithmetic would be two (and ironically they are the most useful now.) Or aren't any done yet. Are all fields being expanded?

Comment: The universe is expanding. Why shouldn't Mathematics?

Comment: Everything mathematicswise that poses a challenge, either applied, intellectual or otherwise, to some mathematician is, has been and/or will be researched. There is active research in arithmetic, algebra, etc., but of course these terms do not necessarily have the meaning high school students usually attach to them...:)

Comment: @Back in a Flash No no no, not mathematics itself. Of course it will grow forever. I am talking about specific fields. (I don't think many people earn a PHD in arithmetic any more.)

Comment: @DonAntonio Oh, so it just changes. I thought they would just abandon certain fields and turn to new ones, but I guess you could keep just growing an old one.

Comment: Some new old fields are so innovative, new and developed that their ressemblance with the old old ones is pretty shaky...

Comment: @BackinaFlash not only is it expanding but its expanding at an accelerating rate ;D

Comment: I don't think any mathematics is ever really finished, as the more we discover the more questions we find!
You could look at some things as being done, such as the classification of all finite simple groups, however this just paved the way into more research, "where do the sporadic groups come from/what are their properties?".
I think most areas that are "completed" in this way unearth more questions than they answer.

Comment: In the early 80s, I was told the area called "the geometry of numbers" was essentially dead. The Wikipedia page seems to indicate "recent results," but it isn't specific - are they significant? That was the only time anybody ever told me that any sub-field of math was dead. (I recall the person telling me that there were some Big Problems left in the field, but nobody thought they could be solved...)

Comment: Geometry of numbers if far from dead, though I don't know enough about the subject to tell you what is happening. Where is the "summon Pete L. Clark" button?

Comment: Branko Grünbaum said (liberally paraphrased) "As soon as you think you've learned absolutely everything there is to know about a particular aspect of mathematics, you realize that you're just getting started." This was during a course in plane geometry, in which he generalized of various things like Ceva's theorem and incircles and Napoleon's Theorem so that they applied to arbitrary polygons. His previous course had been on polyhedra; he joked that his next course would seek-out still-hidden mysteries of the Straight Line. (It didn't happen, but I still kinda wonder it might have included.)

Comment: Some links related to this: [What are strange, obscure, ignored fields of mathematics?](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=542714) at Physics Forums; [Is general topology dead?](http://at.yorku.ca/cgi-bin/bbqa?forum=ask_a_topologist_2000;task=show_msg;msg=0352) at Ask A Topologist.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak: I went to [What are strange, obscure, ignored fields of mathematics](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=542714), expecting to see things like E. H. Moore's General Analysis, invariants/covariants of quantics, and spherical conics. However, instead of things like this, the first posted suggestions were: *From what I've come across, the most dead fields seem to be Calculus of Variations, Morse Theory, and k-theory* (?!?)

Answer (score 1):

A field is "done" when all of its questions are "done."

A question is "done" when everyone is "satisfied by the answers found."

While I think that many fields have famous interesting questions which may be considered "done" because they have satisfactory answers, I think it's almost never the case that all of the questions are "done" in a field. Usually, while you are doing research on a question, lots of questions arise along the way. And then when you finally answer your question, it immediately suggests new questions.

The importance of questions depends on the interest people have in them, and so part of a field being "alive" is whether the topic is "in style" or not. That is going to fluctuate as time passes!